# How to Draw Astronomically Correct Crescent in Pygame or Matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, geometry, astronomy

Pyephem gives me the lunation as a number in [0.0, 1.0], with >0 being just after the new moon and <1 being just before the new moon. So the first quarter, full moon and third quarter are at .25, .5 and .75, respectively.

I am creating a graphical representation for the lunation, ergo, I am trying to render an astronomically correct crescent (or lune?).

My system uses Pygame for audio and graphics, but it appears that filled regions are easier in matplotlib and I have a connector for the two technologies, so solutions may use either technology.

So far, my approach is to render a white circle and a black circle, blit onto a temporary surface, where I adjust the alpha. Later I will compute the name of the current moon, and the background will be selected as a function of the moon name (i.e., wolf moon, blood moon, etc.).

My current code kinda looks like moon phases, but it doesn't look quite right. I'm not sure where to begin in my search for the right parameters... I think the primary problem is figuring out the scale for the eclipsing circle, and then figuring out the correct offset for its center.

```
def arc_patch (ax, lunacity): # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58263608/fill-between-arc-patches-matplotlib
    ax.grid (False)
    xmin = -85 # TODO don't use magic numbers
    xmax = +85
    xrng = xmax - xmin
    ymin = -85
    ymax = +85
    yrng = ymax - ymin
    ax.set_xlim (xmin, xmax)
    ax.set_ylim (ymin, ymax)
    
    # Use a predefined colormap
    colormap = []
    
    # Draw multiple ellipses with different colors and style. All are perfectly superposed
    ellipse = mpl.patches.Ellipse (  # Base one, with big black line for reference
        ORIGIN, xrng, yrng,
        color='k', fill=False, zorder=100) # TODO what is zorder ?

    # Define some clipping paths
    # One for each area
    clips = [
        mpl.patches.Arc ( # the moon, both light and dark
            ORIGIN, xrng, yrng, theta1=0, theta2=360,
            visible=False  # We do not need to display it, just to use it for clipping
        ),
    ]
    colormap.append ('purple') # invisible
    
    if lunacity < .25:       # 0   ,  .25 => new moon, first quarter moon
        print ("q0-q1")
        
        lun = lunacity * 4   # 0   , 1.
        lun = 1 - lun        # 1   , 0.
        lun = 1 / lun        # 1   , inf

        rx, ry = xrng, yrng * lun
    
        X, Y = ORIGIN        # center of light circle
        X = X - (rx / 2) * ((lunacity - 0) * 4)
        x, y = X, Y          # center of dark circle
        Arc1_xy = x, y
        
        # draw light circle, then dark circle
        light_patch = mpl.patches.Ellipse (
            ORIGIN, xrng, yrng,
            visible=False)
        dark_patch = mpl.patches.Ellipse (
            Arc1_xy, rx, ry,
            visible=False)
        colormap.append ('white')
        colormap.append ('black')
        clips.append (light_patch)
        clips.append ( dark_patch)
        
    elif lunacity < .5:       #  .25,  .5  => first quarter moon, full moon
        print ("q1-q2")
        
        assert .25 <= lunacity
        lun = lunacity - .25 # 0.  ,  .25
        assert lun >= 0
        assert lun < .25
        lun = lun * 4        # 0.  , 1.
        assert lun >= 0
        assert lun < 1
        lun = 1 / lun        # inf , 1.
        assert lun >= 1
        print ("lun: %s" % (lun,))
        
        rx, ry = xrng, yrng * lun
    
        X, Y = ORIGIN        # center of dark circle
        X = X + (rx / 2) * (1 - ((lunacity - .25) * 4))
        x, y = X, Y          # center of light circle
        Arc1_xy = x, y
        
        print ("(x: %s, y: %s), (w: %s, h: %s)" % (x, y, rx, ry))
        
        # draw dark circle, then light circle
        dark_patch = mpl.patches.Ellipse (
            ORIGIN, xrng, yrng,
            visible=False)
        light_patch = mpl.patches.Ellipse (
            Arc1_xy, rx, ry,
            visible=False)
        colormap.append ('black')
        colormap.append ('white')
        clips.append ( dark_patch)
        clips.append (light_patch)
    elif lunacity < .75:     #  .5 ,  .75 => full moon, third quarter moon
        print ("q2-q3")
        
        assert .5 <= lunacity
        lun = lunacity - .5  # 0.  ,  .25
        assert lun >= 0
        assert lun < .25
        lun = lun * 4        # 0.  , 1.
        assert lun >= 0
        assert lun < 1
        lun = 1 - lun        # 1.  , 0.
        assert lun > 0
        assert lun <= 1
        lun = 1 / lun        # 1.  , inf
        assert lun >= 1
        print ("lun: %s" % (lun,))
        
        rx, ry = xrng, yrng * lun
    
        X, Y = ORIGIN        # center of light circle
        X = X - (rx / 2) * ((lunacity - .5) * 4)
        x, y = X, Y          # center of dark circle
        Arc1_xy = x, y
        
        print ("(x: %s, y: %s), (w: %s, h: %s)" % (x, y, rx, ry))
        
        # draw dark circle, then light circle
        dark_patch = mpl.patches.Ellipse (
            ORIGIN, xrng, yrng,
            visible=False)
        light_patch = mpl.patches.Ellipse (
            Arc1_xy, rx, ry,
            visible=False)
        colormap.append ('black')
        colormap.append ('white')
        clips.append ( dark_patch)
        clips.append (light_patch)
    elif lunacity < 1.0:     #  .75, 1.   => third quarter moon, full moon
        print ("q3-q4")

        assert .75 <= lunacity
        lun = lunacity - .75 # 0.  ,  .25
        assert lun >= 0
        assert lun < .25
        lun = lun * 4        # 0.  , 1.
        assert lun >= 0
        assert lun < 1
        lun = 1 / lun        # inf , 1.
        assert lun > 1
        print ("lun: %s" % (lun,))
        
        rx, ry = xrng, yrng * lun
    
        X, Y = ORIGIN        # center of light circle
        X = X + (rx / 2) * (1 - ((lunacity - .75) * 4))
        x, y = X, Y          # center of dark circle
        Arc1_xy = x, y
        
        print ("(x: %s, y: %s), (w: %s, h: %s)" % (x, y, rx, ry))
        
        # draw light circle, then dark circle
        light_patch = mpl.patches.Ellipse (
            ORIGIN, xrng, yrng,
            visible=False)
        dark_patch = mpl.patches.Ellipse (
            Arc1_xy, rx, ry,
            visible=False)
        colormap.append ('white')
        colormap.append ('black')
        clips.append (light_patch)
        clips.append ( dark_patch)
    
    n = len (clips)
    # Ellipses for your sub-areas.
    # Add more if you want more areas
    # Apply the style of your areas here (colors, alpha, hatch, etc.)
    areas = [
        mpl.patches.Ellipse (
            ORIGIN, xrng, yrng,  # Perfectly fit your base ellipse
            color=colormap [i], fill=True, alpha=1.0,  # Add some style, fill, color, alpha
            zorder=i)
        for i in range (n)  # Here, we have 4 areas
    ]

    # Add all your components to your axe
    ax.add_patch (ellipse)
    for area, clip in zip (areas, clips):
        ax.add_patch (area)
        ax.add_patch (clip)
        area.set_clip_path (clip)  # Use clipping paths to clip you areas
```

After looking into the problem more, I see that I was looking at the ellipse's axes backward. After revision, I have this, but there's something wrong with the arc start/end angles (it appears that theta1 and theta2 are being honored by matplotlib) or maybe the clip order:

```
if lunacity < .25:       # 0   ,  .25 => new moon, first quarter moon
        print ("q0-q1")
        
        lun = lunacity * 4   # 0   , 1.
        lun = 1 - lun        # 1   , 0.
        
        rx, ry = xrng * lun, yrng
        
        # dark left, dark middle, light right
        light_patch = mpl.patches.Ellipse ( # right half
            ORIGIN, xrng, yrng, visible=False) # theta1=-90, theta2=+90
        dark_patch = mpl.patches.Ellipse ( # center
            ORIGIN, rx, ry,
            visible=False)
        dark_patch2 = mpl.patches.Arc ( # left half
            ORIGIN, xrng, yrng, theta1=+90, theta2=+270,
            visible=False)
        colormap.append ('black')
        colormap.append ('white')
        colormap.append ('black')
        clips.append ( dark_patch2)
        clips.append (light_patch)
        clips.append ( dark_patch)
        
    elif lunacity < .5:       #  .25,  .5  => first quarter moon, full moon
        print ("q1-q2")
        
        assert .25 <= lunacity
        lun = lunacity - .25 # 0.  ,  .25
        assert lun >= 0
        assert lun < .25
        lun = lun * 4        # 0.  , 1.
        assert lun >= 0
        assert lun < 1
        
        rx, ry = xrng * lun, yrng
        
        # dark left, light middle, light right
        light_patch2 = mpl.patches.Ellipse (  # right
            ORIGIN, xrng, yrng, visible=False) # theta1=-90, theta2=+90
        dark_patch = mpl.patches.Arc (  # left
            ORIGIN, xrng, yrng, theta1=+90, theta2=+270,
            visible=False)
        light_patch = mpl.patches.Ellipse (  # middle
            ORIGIN, rx, ry,
            visible=False)
        colormap.append ('white')
        colormap.append ('black')
        colormap.append ('white')
        clips.append (light_patch2)
        clips.append ( dark_patch)
        clips.append (light_patch)
    elif lunacity < .75:     #  .5 ,  .75 => full moon, third quarter moon
        print ("q2-q3")
        
        assert .5 <= lunacity
        lun = lunacity - .5  # 0.  ,  .25
        assert lun >= 0
        assert lun < .25
        lun = lun * 4        # 0.  , 1.
        assert lun >= 0
        assert lun < 1
        lun = 1 - lun        # 1.  , 0.
        assert lun > 0
        assert lun <= 1
        rx, ry = xrng * lun, yrng
    
        # light left, light middle, dark right
        light_patch2 = mpl.patches.Ellipse (  # left
            ORIGIN, xrng, yrng, visible=False) # theta1=+90, theta2=+270,
        dark_patch = mpl.patches.Arc (  # right
            ORIGIN, xrng, yrng, theta1=-90, theta2=+90,
            visible=False)
        light_patch = mpl.patches.Ellipse (  # middle
            ORIGIN, rx, ry,
            visible=False)
        colormap.append ('white')
        colormap.append ('black')
        colormap.append ('white')
        clips.append (light_patch2)
        clips.append ( dark_patch)
        clips.append (light_patch)
    elif lunacity < 1.0:     #  .75, 1.   => third quarter moon, full moon
        print ("q3-q4")

        assert .75 <= lunacity
        lun = lunacity - .75 # 0.  ,  .25
        assert lun >= 0
        assert lun < .25
        lun = lun * 4        # 0.  , 1.
        assert lun >= 0
        assert lun < 1
        
        rx, ry = xrng * lun , yrng
        
        # light left, dark middle, dark right
        dark_patch2 = mpl.patches.Ellipse (  # right
            ORIGIN, xrng, yrng, visible=False) # theta1=-90, theta2=+90
        light_patch = mpl.patches.Arc (  # left
            ORIGIN, xrng, yrng, theta1=+90, theta2=+270,
            visible=False)
        dark_patch = mpl.patches.Ellipse (  # middle
            ORIGIN, rx, ry,
            visible=False)
        colormap.append ('black')
        colormap.append ('white')
        colormap.append ('black')
        clips.append ( dark_patch2)
        clips.append (light_patch)
        clips.append ( dark_patch)
```

Answer (score 0):

Geometry:

> "The shape of the lit side of a spherical body (most notably the Moon) that appears to be less than half illuminated by the Sun as seen by the viewer appears in a different shape from what is generally termed a crescent in planar geometry: Assuming the terminator lies on a great circle, the crescent Moon will actually appear as the figure bounded by a half-ellipse and a half-circle, with the major axis of the ellipse coinciding with a diameter of the semicircle."

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crescent#Shape)

I couldn't figure out why patches.Arc didn't make use of theta1 and theta2, so I switched to patches.Rectangle:

```
light_patch2 = mpl.patches.Rectangle (  # right
            *rrect, visible=False)
        dark_patch = mpl.patches.Rectangle (  # left
            *lrect, visible=False)
        light_patch = mpl.patches.Ellipse (  # middle
            ORIGIN, rx, ry, visible=False)
        colormap.append ('white')
        colormap.append ('black')
        colormap.append ('white')
        clips.append (light_patch2)
        clips.append ( dark_patch)
        clips.append (light_patch)
```